# SPLITTING COLUMN BY DELIMITER INTO UNIQUE ROWS IN HIVE

Tags: hive

I have a dataset. Please see below a sample row:

94654   6802D326-9F9B-4FC8-B2DD-F878EADE31F2    1460695483:440507;1460777656:440515;1460778054:440488;1460778157:440481,440600;

Each column is separated by a space(in total 3 columns). The columns names are id (int), unid (string), time_stamp (string).

I would like to split the dataset such that the each unique element such into the below rows:-

- 94654   6802D326-9F9B-4FC8-B2DD-F878EADE31F2    1460695483:440507
- 94654   6802D326-9F9B-4FC8-B2DD-F878EADE31F2    1460777656:440515
- 94654   6802D326-9F9B-4FC8-B2DD-F878EADE31F2    1460778054:440488
- 94654   6802D326-9F9B-4FC8-B2DD-F878EADE31F2    1460778157:440481
- 94654   6802D326-9F9B-4FC8-B2DD-F878EADE31F2    1460778157:440600

Each sub-point is each row. I have used the following query but it is giving me the output like above. I have used the following code and it is not working:-

select id, unid,time_date
from table 
LATERAL VIEW explode (SPLIT (time_date,'\;')) time_date as time_date;

Output:-
94654   6802D326-9F9B-4FC8-B2DD-F878EADE31F2    1460695483:440507;1460777656:440515;1460778054:440488;1460778157:440481,440600; (THE FOLLOWING ROW IS REPEATED 5 times)

Help would be appreciated! Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I had to replace the semi-colons with a pipe.  So:

```
CREATE temporary TABLE tbl 
(id int,
unid string,
time_stamp string);

INSERT INTO tbl 
VALUES (
94654, '6802D326-9F9B-4FC8-B2DD-F878EADE31F2' , '1460695483:440507|1460777656:440515|1460778054:440488|1460778157:440481,440600');

SELECT
id,
unid,
time_stamp
FROM
(
SELECT
id,
unid,
split(time_stamp,'\\|')  ts
FROM
tbl
) t
lateral VIEW explode(t.ts) bar AS time_stamp;
```

Which give us:

```
94654   6802D326-9F9B-4FC8-B2DD-F878EADE31F2    1460695483:440507
94654   6802D326-9F9B-4FC8-B2DD-F878EADE31F2    1460777656:440515
94654   6802D326-9F9B-4FC8-B2DD-F878EADE31F2    1460778054:440488
94654   6802D326-9F9B-4FC8-B2DD-F878EADE31F2    1460778157:440481,440600
```

You have to do the split and explode in separate steps. So we do the split in a derived table, and the explode/lateral view in the outer query.

Comment: Thank you so much Andrew!:)